# Normally distributed effect size

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I have read in several articles that effect sizes (like Cohen's d or Hedges g) can be considered to be normally distributed around the population effect size for large samples. On what basis can we say this? Is the calculation of the variance of d based on this statement?

Comment: Is it not the central limit theorem?

Comment: @POC Often the CLT doesn't apply, because the effect size is a *ratio,* rather than a mean.  Much depends on how the effect size is computed and on the underlying model.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer here : Larry Hedges Journal of Educational Statistics, Summer, 1981, Vol. 6, No. 2, p.117 :
I quote (p.117) : When the number of experiments to be combined is large or the degrees of freedom of the experiments are large, the computations involved in the method of Walker and Saw become tedious. In this case, the normal approximation to the noncentral t-distribution is quite good (see Johnson & Welch, 1939) and much simpler to compute. The normal approximation to the noncentral t-distribution treats each g (The Hedges g nowadays) as if it were normally distributed with mean the effect size (the parameter).